# Can I get bing.com search results in JSON without AppID

Tags: json, bing, msn

Can I get bing.com search results in JSON without AppID.

I found that I can [get bing search results in JSON](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd250846.aspx), but it seem to require appid. I wonder if tehre is another way without teh appid. I just want to use it for my own need in console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What type of results do you want to get? Web results only?

I think that the easiest way is to use rss. You will get XML but it is easy to transform it to json.
Use URL like:

http://www.bing.com/search?format=rss&q=seattle